# Proving that a sequence is strictly monotonic increasing

Tags: sequences-and-series

So I have

[image]

With Bernoulli's inequality, I get:

[image]

I especially don't understand the step marked and I don't understand how dividing the next member by its predecessor pertains to Bernoulli's inequality and how proving a ratio  of one between those two members proves monotonc increasing function.

Hence we get:

[image]

Again, where is Bernoulli here? I assume that if $(1+x)^n>1+nx$, then $x=\frac{1}{n+1}$ on the left, but why is there a power on the right, if there isn't one in the Bernoulli inequality?

Comment: Apply Bernoulli on $x=-\frac 1{(n+1)^2},$ and take the power to be $n+1,$ then we have the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Set $x=-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$. Then what was done in the step marked by you is:

$$\left(1-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\right)^{n+1}=(1+x)^{n+1}>1+(n+1)x=1-(n+1)\cdot\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$$

In the middle we have used Bernoulli's inequality (for $n+1$ instead of $n$).

Altogether this whole calculation gives $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}>1$, i.e. $a_{n+1}>a_n$ (that explains the "hence we get (..)" part of your question). As you observed correctly, this is not yet another use of Bernoulli's inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: In the Bernoulli's inequality $x$ in your case is $\frac{-1}{(n+1)^2}$ and $n$ is $n+1$.

And for the overall inequality take the left-most term that is the ratio between the $n$-th term and it's successor and the value $1$ you got at the end. Multiplying by the $n+1$-th term you get the desired result.